# Getting uid of a firestore reference field in React

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
this.props.firebase.referenceListItems()
```

I'm iterating over the `referenceListItems`, and trying to get a reference field. The current document in the loop is called `referenceListItem`.

Example document in the `referenceListItems` collections:

```
created: April 30, 2019 at 12:41:41 AM UTC+2 (timestamp)
name: "Name"
referenceList:
  0: /referenceLists/YzBh0E3pQGB65us1BpVP
```

How do I access the uid part of the reference field?

`referenceListItem.referenceList[0]` doesn't return a string.

Comment: What is `typeof document.referenceList[0]`? It's either a string or an odd regex...

Comment: it's a firebase reference field.

Comment: Try calling `toString`. Does it work (e.g. return a string)?

Comment: No it doesn't, it's some kind of object.

Comment: What is it? `[object Object]`? Or does it contain the reference field as a string somewhere?

Comment: Could you edit the question to show the code you're working with?  It's not clear to me if you've already queried Firestore, and now you have a snapshot in hand, or if you haven't yet queried and are looking to get a hold of something specific.

Comment: Not that I can see! It's [DocumentReference]

Comment: @DougStevenson Done. Any more clarifications needed, lemme know.

Comment: What is `document` in your code?  How did you get a hold of it?  Help us understand how to you got where you are now.  Optimally, show the query, and how you're processing it.

Comment: @DougStevenson I've edited the question, it's simply a single firestore document, in this case a `referenceListItem`, which is a document in the `referenceListItems` collection.

Comment: `referenceListItem` isn't a native Firestore data type.  You're working with something that we have no context for understanding what it is.

Comment: @DougStevenson It's not a data type, it's a document from a firestore collection! I've tried to clarify, hopefully that sheds some light on it.

Comment: Yeah, it's not clear, because you haven't explained what a `referenceListItem` is.  That's not a Firestore native data type.  But I'll take a guess at what you're doing anyway.

Comment: If the answer I've given isn't helpful, consider editing the question to show the actual query that you're making, and how you're processing the results of that query.  Something had to assign this `referenceListItem`, but you're just not showing what that is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's difficult to tell what exactly you're working with.  Maybe some custom data, I don't know.  `referenceListItem` isn't the name of something provided natively by Firestore.  Perhaps you are using some layer of abstraction around the Firestore SDK.  So, since it's not clear what you have here, I'll just take a guess at what's going on.

It sounds like you may have stored a [DocumentReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference) type object in an array in a document in Firestore, and you're trying to read it back out.  If you query for that document, the resulting [DocumentSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot) will contain array field with [DocumentReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference) type objects.

If you have a DocumentReference object in hand, and you want to get the ID of the document that it's reference, you can simply use its [id property](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference.html#id) to get that string.  So maybe `referenceListItem.referenceList[0].id` will be what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the help, that's exactly what it is. I'm having a bit of trouble finding the right words, If you wanna help edit the question for future reference, more than welcome :)

Comment: What's missing is the code that you used to query the database. I can't see what you've written, though.

Comment: It's a huge chunk, it has listener attached as well, and multiple components rendering. So I figured it'd be easier this way. Apparently not!

Comment: It's expected that people asking questions on Stack Overflow provide a [minimal, complete, viable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), in order to get help with their problems.  It's easier for everyone if you do that, so there is no ambiguity or uncertainty in what you're asking.